# Error al imprimir cadena extraída de un texto de telegram

Tags: python, telegram

Estoy intensado extraer el mensaje de Telegram pero me da un fallo al imprimir el mensaje.
No como usar la codificación, la necesito en español.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''
username = ''
channel_username = ''

client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

#for message in client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=1):
#    print(message.message)


for message in client.iter_messages(channel_username,limit=10):
    a = message.message.encode("utf-8")
    print(a.decode("utf-8"))
```

Me lanza el error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\jtmilla\Desktop\telegram-analysis-master\telegram.py", line 17, in 
> print(a.decode("utf-8"))
> File "C:\Users\jtmilla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 32-33: character maps to

[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.365 seconds

Comment: Ademas, no entendi bien tu objetivo. Que cosa "necesitas en español"? Las ñ y las letras con tildes se convierten en caracteres sin sentido?

Comment: No entiendo, ¿por qué el encode y decode?

Comment: Lo que quiero es obtener el mensaje de Telegram no si habrá un metodo, si lo quito me da este error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 32-33: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Viendo la documentacion, parece que message.message te devuelve el contenido del mensaje como una cadena. Podrias explicarnos por que eso no te sirve por favor?

Comment: Lo quiero es almacenar un mensaje de Telegram con una codificación en español mas caracteres especiales como el euro.

Comment: Python maneja los strings en Unicode; puede almacenar cualquier caracter/logograma/emoji que exista

Comment: Mmmm no se nada y ni siquiera uso telegram, pero si me das una cadena de ejemplo en el cual message.message no te guarde esos caracteres especiales, podria darte una solucion. Eso si, mi idea puede no ser la mejor alternativa, pero podria servirte para zafar mientras esperas una mejor respuesta.

Comment: la cadena seria la convertir a castellano:

Comment: Creo que se te olvido la cadena...

Comment: cadena que imprime: '@fdfdf�' cadena original: @fdfdfç me pasa con los caracteres especiales como la ñ, o los  de emollis,

Comment: Mmmmm, pensé que podría trabajar con la cadena y obtener la original, pero ni siquiera se si se puede. Sin embargo, mirando la documentación, hay dos argumentos que me llaman la atención cuando creas el cliente: lang_code y system_lang_code. Probaste pasar lang_code="es" y/o system_lang_code="es", para indicarle que eso debe estar en español? Te dejo el link donde vi esto que digo: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.telegramclient.TelegramClient